# Count total number of edges in binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to write one method to compute the total number of edges in a binary tree. I was trying recursion because it can be computed based on the number of nodes - 1, but wasn't sure how to subtract one at the end of recursion. Because of that, I am trying to update a variable "count" and just subtract one at the end. I was wondering if this is the best approach, or if I should try another way.

```
public int numOfEdges(Node v){
    int count;  
    if(isLeaf(v){  
        count = 0; 
    }  
    else{  
        count = 1 + numOfEdges(left(v)) + numOfEdges(right(v));  
    }  
    return count - 1;  
}
```

Comment: Do you require it to be in one method, or could you just make another method called `numOfNodes` and subtract one?

Comment: By "edge" do you mean path or leaves?

Comment: Recursion is fine. Using numOfNodes - 1 would be fine too. But if you use straight recursion you should test **left** `++1?` and **right** `++1?`. As that are the edges.

Comment: "Edge" refers to path, not leaves

Comment: Why not just write two functions, one that counts nodes, and the other, which counts the number of nodes and subtracts one?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be easiest to accomplish by just writing two different methods, a common technique when using recursion:

```
private int numNodesIn(Node v) {
    if (v == null) return 0;
    return 1 + numNodesIn(v.left) + numNodesIn(v.right);
}

public int numEdgesIn(Node v) {
    return v == null? 0 : numNodesIn(v) - 1;
}
```